# HTTPURLConnection with SOCKS proxy

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, socks

I have launched a machine on Amazon EC2 and only have port 22 open to the world (so only SSH to the machine is allowed). I created a tunnel to the machine using:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -C -N -D '*:20022' -i <ssh_key_file> -o ServerAliveInterval=20 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null ec2-user@ec2-a-b-c-d.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Note that the above is a public DNS.

The tunnel works fine, because I'm getting correct output when I run a curl command:

```
curl --proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:20022 https://ec2-a-b-c-d.compute-1.amazonaws.com:<my_port>
```

However, I'm not able to establish connection using Java and HTTPURLConnection using the same SOCKS proxy. Here's the piece of code:

```
import sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String urlString = "http://ec2-a-b-c-d.compute-1.amazonaws.com:<my_port>";

  URL url = new URL(urlString);
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", 20022));
  System.out.println("Opening connection: " + url.toString() + " with proxy: " + proxy);
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);

  conn.connect();
  return 0;
}
```

It times out with the following stack trace at "conn.connect()" (line numbers not accurate)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:129)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:502)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:976)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
    at com.rajat.http_connection.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:53)
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: Actually, the way you connect SOCKS proxy works fine in my case. Just wanted to say thank you :P